# Best practice for multiple AJAX API calls that require a response from the previous call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I'm working on an internal page that allows a user to upload a CSV with resources and dates, and have the page add all the scheduling information for these resources to our management software.  There's a pretty decent API for doing this, and I have a working model, but it seems...cludgy.

For each resource I have to start a new session, then create a new reservation, then add resources, then confirm that the reservation isn't blocked, then submit the reservation. Most of the calls return a variable I need for the next step in the process, so each relies on the previous ajax call.

Currently I'm doing this via nested ajax calls similar to this:

```
$.ajax('startnewsession').then($.ajax('createreservation').then('etcetc'))
```

While this works, I feel like there has to be an easier, or more "proper" way to do it, both for cleaner code and for adaptability.

Comment: I usually split my data into array of chunks. Then, send the first chunk (with index 0), and move to the next chunk (index) on `complete` event of `$.ajax`. In your scenario, you might want to take a look at [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: If you have to rely on the output of previous ajax call for making next ajax call, then i think $.when might not help. If you have this series of ajax call always, then can we wrap all logic in single service to avoid roundtrips?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is correct, assuming you can't change the API you are communicating with.

There's really no way of getting around having to do some sort of nested ajax calls if you need the response data of the previous one for the next one. Promises (`.then`) however make it a bit more pretty than having to do callbacks.

The proper solution (if possible) would of course be to implement your API in such a way that it would require less roundtrips from the client to the server. Considering there's no user input in between each of these steps in the negotiation process for creating a reservation, your API should be able to complete the entire flow for creating a reservation, without having to contact the client until it needs more input from the user.

Just remember to do some error handling between each of the ajax calls in case they should fail - you don't want to start creating the following up API calls with corrupt data from a previously failed request.

```
var baseApiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
$.ajax(baseApiUrl + '/posts/1')
  .then(function(post) {
    $.ajax(baseApiUrl + '/users/' + post.userId)
      .then(function(user) {
        console.log('got name: ' + user.name);
      }, function(error) {
        console.log('error when calling /users/', error)
      });
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('error when calling /posts/', error)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: as usual I'm trying to do some chains like this:

```
ajaxCall1.then(
  response => ajaxCall2(response)
).then(
  response => ajaxCall3(response)
)
```

I'm trying to avoid using of `when`. As usual I (and bet you too) have 1 ajax call (for form submit), sometimes 2 chaining ajax calls, for an example, if I need to get data for table, first query for total rows count, and if count greater than 0, another call for data. In this case I'm using:

```
    function getGridData() {
      var count;
      callForRowsCount().then(
         (response) => {
            count = response;
            if(count > 0) {
              return callForData();
            } else {
              return [];
            }
         }
      ).then(response => {
         pub.fireEvent({
           type: 'grid-data',
           count: count,
           data: response
         })
      })
}
```

`pub`lisher trigger event, and I have all my components updated.

In some realy rare cases, I need to use `when`. But this is always bad design. It happen in case, when I need to load pack of additional data before of main request, or when backend not support bulk update, and I need to send pack of ajax calls to update many of database entities. Something like this:

```
var whenArray = [];
if(require1) {
  whenArray.push(ajaxCall1);
}
if(require2) {
  whenArray.push(ajaxCall2);
}
if(require3) {
  whenArray.push(ajaxCall3);
}
$.when.apply($, whenArray).then(() => loadMyData(arguments));
```